# Low internal storage from 32GB to 200 MB

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, internal-sd

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini I9190.

When I download apps from the Google Play Store I get a notification stating that I have low space and requesting that I delete some apps. The available internal storage space on my phone is 32GB...

How can I fix the problem and use the internal memory?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! The available "internal storage" (or SDCard) has nothing to do with that. The error refers to *device storage*. For details and some first aid, please take a look at our fine [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info). Being a frequent question, this has been answered on this site already multiple times (links to those answers are included with before-mentioned tag-wiki).

Answer (score 1):

The Galaxy s4 mini only comes with an 8gb internal storage (5gb are usable), i think you are referring to your external storage and you can use this space by moving some apps to it.

You can achieve that by installing an app called "app 2 sd"  by sam lu, it is very simple to use application, hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of Android do not allow apps to be on SD (no app will make it happen if this is the case, unless you are rooted). To free up space try using an app like Clean Master.